# Applying a Dynamic row color in a table Javascript/VBscript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

Im using ASP for my webpages together with HTML5 and CSS3 for my thesis project. I was wondering on how to color a row depending on the Subject because I am making a scheduling system to make it easily visible. So if a user made an entry information, it will popup on the table as a subject code, I'd like that row to be colored uniquely and same color with other rows so long as they have same subject code. E.g. Math=red, English=blue. 2 Math subjects=still red, 4 English=still blue all other empty rows=white. Is this possible? I'm looking for either javascript or vbscript. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What control are you using for table rendering?

Comment: If you provided some sample code of your table then we could give some advice on how you can solve your problem.

Comment: a simple html code like this: <table width="920" height="80"border="1" align="left"> then some vbscripts to add and fetch to my database

Comment: im sorry the table code is too long because of the vbscripts included im new in this site. can't upload an image of the table also

Comment: <tr>    
  <td><div align="center">10:30AM-12:00PM</div></td> 
<%
 For i = 1 to x

  course_c=Recordsetx.Fields(0)
  get2=Recordsetx.Fields(1)

  SQL ="Select distinct(Subject_Block) From dbo.tbl_Faculty_Load where Course_code='"&course_c&"' and School_Year='"&school_year&"' and Subject_Year='"&stud_year&"' and Semester='"&sem&"' Order by Subject_Block ASC"

     Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
     Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

     Connection.Open ConnString
    
     Recordset.Open SQL,ConnString

Comment: Do While Not Recordset.EOF   

   sub_block= Recordset.Fields(0)   

   SQL ="Select Subject_Code, Remarks From dbo.tbl_Faculty_Load where Course_code='"&course_c&"' and School_Year='"&school_year&"' and Subject_Year='"&stud_year&"'and Semester='"&sem&"' and Subject_Block='"&sub_block&"' and Subject_Day='S' and Time_Sched='10:30AM-12:00PM' Order by Subject_Block ASC"

      Set Connectiony = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      Set Recordsety = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

      Connectiony.Open ConnString
    
      Recordsety.Open SQL,ConnString

Comment: If (Recordsety.EOF) Then
%>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="text"  size="10"></div></td>
<%

Comment: sir the above code is the part where I output the information entered into the table

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate `<tr>` template tag
2. add something like `<tr class="response.write(SubjectNameToCssClass(<somearg>))" ... >`
3. Add CSS:

   .red-row {
       background-color: red;
   }